# iMac monitor unexpectedly comes back on

Tags: applications, imac, sleep-wake, display, settings

I turn the monitor off (using <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>eject</kbd>) while listening to music on my iMac 27". But recently it has starting coming back on almost right away, which I assume is from the vibration of the speaker nearby. Is there some sort of sensitivity adjustment to avoid the monitor from turning on (until I turn it on myself)?

Comment: Thanks for the good answer but it seems stranger than that. I just played a few tunes in my iTunes library and the monitor stayed off. It was while watching a youtube video that I earlier noticed it coming back on so I played 3 other youtube videos and the monitor light came back on within about 5 seconds every time.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the display to sleep, it turns back on when the computer detects a key press or mouse movement or mouse click. In your case, it seems like your speaker vibration is causing the mouse to move, and thus waking up the display. The best workarounds are to avoid mouse movement by moving the speaker away from the mouse or placing the mouse on a surface that absorbs the speaker's vibrations or reducing the speaker volume.

Note that you could reduce the sensitivity of the mouse by going to `System Preferences` > `Mouse` and then selecting a slower `Tracking` speed. But this would also likely make your system difficult to use - you'd have to physically move the mouse farther to move the cursor by a particular distance on the screen - and you may have to switch between two levels of sensitivity (slow and faster) often if you're not happy with the slow tracking setting for normal use.